# Ominous "8.5 GB Volume" on MomentusXT under 12.10

Tags: 12.10, partitioning, gparted

I'm looking for people who also have their Ubunutu/Linux running on a MomentusXT ST750LX003. A partitiion/volume is shown to me that I can't mount, nor really place where it comes from. It is formatted in HFS+ and about 8GB large. Could the drive have a defect and show me the SSD cache? I read ["Is Seagate's new “FAST Factor Boot” technology compatible with Ubuntu?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143578/is-seagates-new-fast-factor-boot-technology-compatible-with-ubuntu), that it shouldn't.

Please find screenshots from both GParted, the error I receive when trying to open and from Windows 7 drive manager.

[image]
[image]

It's not a dual-boot system on the MomentusXT, rather Ubuntu is installed alone on it, while Windows 7 is on an extra SSD `SYSTEM (C:)`. `DATEN (D:)` is a regular HDD.

Thanks for any advice what this volume could be, and/or how to solve the mounting error. Preferably, please check your own MomentusXTs in GParted and let me know if this ~8GB HFS+ volume appears as well.

Comment: Have you tried to mount it manually and see what it contains: `sudo mount -t hfsplus /dev/sdb5 ~/<some_temporary_folder>`? Maybe that is just a partition with software/manuals to OSX.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a regular disk partition that you, or somebody, created and it looks like it has a corrupted hfs filesystem on it.  If it doesn't have any data in it you care about, then blow it away.

Answer (score 0):

The command you suggested results in "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb5, missing codepage or helper program, or other error. In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try dmesg | tail  or so"

dmesg | tail reports "hfs: invalid secondary volume header" and "hfs: unable to find HFS+ superblock"

Would it make sense to try and merge the volume into my main Ubuntu partition with GParted?

Thanks and greetings!