# How to check if SSHD works?

Tags: performance, ssd

I have a Laptop with an 500 GB SSHD and running Ubuntu on it. A friend of mine told me he is not sure if Ubuntu is even capable of taking advantage in terms of performance of this technology. So my question is if this is true and if there is a way to check if the SSD cache really is used.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/540567/how-to-design-partitions-for-sshd - it definitely is OS independent.

Comment: Your friend is talking about things he knows nothing about.  **;-)** This is hardware that is OS independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Benchmark it. There are maufacturer performance numbers. If you hit those, you know it's working.

In short, install `fs_mark` and `dbench`, run them and compare those to [known values](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=seagate_sshd_linux&num=2).